# Git compatible website deployment tool, something like deployHQ but installed locally

Tags: php, git, web-deployment

Whats the best deployment tool, solution that runs on Windows, can be installed locally, and doesent require much configuration, to deploy PHP projects from different git branches to their webservers (ftp and sftp).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I used [phing](http://www.phing.info/)
and it's very easy to connect to git, just write a config xml file and you're ready to go.

for example, this is a snippet of a git clone within the xml file:

```
    <gitclone
        repository="{rep path}"
        targetPath="{target on local}" />
```

Answer (score 5):

If you are looking forward to deploying over the git (or https) protocol itself, you have tools like **Github for Windows** and **Atlassian Sourcetree**. SFTP can be achieved using **Filezilla**.

If you are looking for a platform like deployHQ, there is [**Codeship**](http://codeship.io). They are a *continuous integration and deployment* service that helps you deploy git repositories by connecting to your GitHub and Bitbucket repositories

I could suggest something better and relevant, if you could elaborate what deployment procedure you have in mind

Comment: I personally use SourceTree to deploy Rails projects to Heroku, and PHP projects to Fortrabbit, over the git protocol.

Answer (score 4):

I’ve written a little PHP script that heps with that. It si called PHPloy and is tightly-coupled with Git to determine what which files where edited/added/deleted and uploads them accordingly. You put your FTP details in a deploy.ini file and run just a command to deploy:

```
phploy
```

You can also deploy to multiple servers at once. And if you have multiple servers configured, you can select to deploy to one of them like this:

```
phploy --server staging
```

There is more that can be done – check it out on Github: https://github.com/banago/PHPloy